# Append to dictionary in Python

Tags: json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the below code and would expect my dictionary `tag` to have as many entries as I get `.`s printed to the screen. I, however, end up with a single entry only, as shown by the bottom print. Each `id` is unique, i.e. I expect a separate entry per `id`. How do I correctly do I do this correctly?

```
tag={}
for id in tags:

    ipm = {"test":[{ "name": "TestOne", "risk": 3},{ "name": "TestTwo", "risk": 2},{ "name": "TestThree", "risk": 1}]}
    post={"post_1":ipm}

    tag={id:post}
    x={}
    tag.update(tag)
    print(".")

print(json.dumps(tag))
```

Comment: well, that is because you keep making `tag`a dict with one entry `tag={id:post}`. just `tag.update({id:post})`

Comment: @Thomas DUH! Lol, Thanks Sir! You can move the comment to an answer and I'll gladly accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your dictionary only contains one entry is because you reassign it

```
tag={id:post}
```

before you update. Just update it with the new value.

```
tag.update({id:post})
```